# Google maps navigation (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, swift3

i'm a beginner and i have created this VC

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

class FinalClass: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomInfoView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!


    var userLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var places:[QPlace] = []
    var index:Int = -1

    var mapView:GMSMapView!
    var marker:GMSMarker?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard index >= 0, places.count > 0 else {
            return

        }

        let place = places[index]
        let lat = place.location?.latitude ?? 1.310844
        let lng = place.location?.longitude ?? 103.866048

        // Google map view
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lng, zoom: 12.5)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
        self.containerView.addSubview(mapView)

        // Add gesture
        addSwipeGesture()

        didSelect(place: place)
        if userLocation != nil {
            addMarkerAtCurrentLocation(userLocation!)
        }
    }

    func addSwipeGesture() {
        let directions: [UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection] = [.right, .left]
        for direction in directions {
            let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
            gesture.direction = direction
            self.bottomInfoView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        }
    }

    func addMarkerAtCurrentLocation(_ userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D)  {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = userLocation
        marker.title = "Your location"
        marker.map = mapView
    }

    func didSelect(place:QPlace) {

        guard let coordinates = place.location else {
            return
        }

        // clear current marker
        marker?.map = nil

        // add marker
        marker = GMSMarker()
        marker?.position = coordinates
        marker?.title = place.name
        marker?.map = mapView
        mapView.selectedMarker = marker
        moveToMarker(marker!)

        // update bottom info panel view
        let desc = place.getDescription()
        descriptionLabel.text = desc.characters.count > 0 ? desc : "-"
        distanceLabel.text = "-"

        // update distance
        if userLocation != nil {
            let dist = distance(from: userLocation!, to: coordinates)
            distanceLabel.text = String.init(format: "Distance %.2f meters", dist)
        }

        title = place.name
    }

    func moveToMarker(_ marker: GMSMarker) {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: marker.position.latitude,
                                              longitude: marker.position.longitude,
                                              zoom: 12.5)
        self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
    }

    // distance between two coordinates
    func distance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let from = CLLocation(latitude: from.latitude, longitude: from.longitude)
        let to = CLLocation(latitude: to.latitude, longitude: to.longitude)
        return from.distance(from: to)
    }

    func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        guard index >= 0, places.count > 0 else {
            return
        }

        if sender.direction == .left {
            if index < places.count - 2 {
                index += 1
                didSelect(place: places[index])
            }
        } else if sender.direction == .right {
            if index > 1 {
                index -= 1
                didSelect(place: places[index])
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func lastBack(_ sender: Any) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

where (with the help of user localization in the previous VC) is shown the goole map with two markers, one on the user position and one on the position of the place searched in the previous VC (with also some info like distance ecc.) What i'm trying to do is to add the navigation between the two points, so i would like that when the view load, automatically the navigation start. The problem is i really do not know how to implement this feature, i looked for some tutorial but no one who fits well with my code.
this is the code in the previous VC to find the user location

```
extension NearbyPlacesViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

        didReceiveUserLocation(userLocation)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error \(error)")
        errorGettingCurrentLocation(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        } else if status == .denied || status == .restricted {
            errorGettingCurrentLocation("Location access denied")
        }
    }

    func errorGettingCurrentLocation(_ errorMessage:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So the start point for navigation is the user location, the end is represented by `let coordinates = place.location`

Comment: so what is first point (start) and which one is the finish point?

Comment: @swift2geek i edited the question, the point to start is the user location, the end is represented by let coordinates = place.location